# Change file type association in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, restructuredtext, file-association

I have a file in PyCharm and its used to be just a `.txt` file.
Now I wanted to use `.rst` (reStructuredText).

I know that when I open a file without an ending for the first time PyCharm asks me what kind of file it is and how the syntax should therefore be interpreted.

Can I open up that dialog again somehow, or can I change the association in some other way?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Actually, @CrazyCoder is right:
If you accidentally mis-labeled the file, PyCharm remembers it and sets a "pattern" for the new file based on the name.

So go to `Settings` | `Editor` | `File Types`, find the type you accidentally mislabeled and remove it from the "Registered Patterns" list.

For example, I mislabed "osm.py" as text file, so under "Text files" I have:

```
*.bat
*.cgi
.
.
.
osm.py
```

Remove it and you get your py file colors back! You can also register a file association where there is no extension. By default this is associated as "Text file".

More on [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-registering-file-types.html).

Comment: i have multiple file types that a certain file may accidentally touch so im trying to fix that. how do i check which file type the active window is associated with?

Answer (score 16):

See `Settings`| `Editor` | `File Types`.

Comment: i saw that but it doesn't help, my file does have the right ending I changed it to .rst from nothing. But it still doesn't recognize it...

Comment: If you remove the present extension from all the file types, then you will get the same dialog again when you try to open a file with unknown file type.

Comment: Also, just my opinion, why not associate it with html?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still cannot find it: under `Settings` | `Editor` | `File Types` menu, look for: `Files Opened In Associated Applications` - see if you can spot there the full name of the problematic file and **remove** it.

Comment: where is it now on mac can't find that

Comment: got to go to wildcards under it and just re associate it

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and noticed that if I 'Invalidate Caches' under the File menu I was able to trigger a re-asking of the file type.

Definitely not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm > Preferences > Editor > File Type > Recognised file types > Select one (e.g., Javascript) > Registered Patterns (+ add wildcard * > apply > - remove wildcard).

This worked for me to get my files associated with the right type.