# How can I redefine my .wav file as HTML file?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am uploading my .wav audio media from my Django admin page and accidentally specified Pycharm to read my .wav as TEXT files. I want to redefine it as HTML; how can I do it in Pycharm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm change file type association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889982/pycharm-change-file-type-association)

Comment: Yeah! That way works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shortcut ctrl+shift+a for "actions menu". Then type "associate", click on "associate with file type". In opened window select "open matching files in associated application". 
[image]