# Disable IdeaVim for certain filetypes

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I'd like to disable IdeaVim for certain filetypes (e.g., .ipynb) in PyCharm.

I can disable IdeaVim from `Tool > Vim Emulator` temporarily. However, it bothers me to turn on/off Vim Emulator every time I switch between Jupyter and Python script. Is there any way to configure whether to use IdeaVim by file extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm change file type association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889982/pycharm-change-file-type-association)

Comment: Thanks @bad_coder, but the article is about PyCharm filetype association, and is not for IdeaVim plugin. I want to specify the filetypes which IdeaVim will be applied to.

Answer (score 1):

I also searched for a few hours for a solution but was unable to find a solution apart from this:

You could create a Keyboard Shortcut for turning it on/off. You find it in Preferences | Keymap | Pugins | IdeaVim | Vim Emulator

If you have a MacBook Pro you could also include it in your Touch Bar, which is also neat. Go To Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars | Touch Bar and add it as an Action